# Django signal not working with django-paypal

Tags: python, django, paypal

I am trying to handle the signal `valid_ipn_received` from the package django-paypal (docs: https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/ipn.html)

engine/signals.py

```
from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received
from engine.models import DatasetRequest
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    print('test')
    ipn_obj = sender
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
        # WARNING !
        # Check that the receiver email is the same we previously
        # set on the `business` field. (The user could tamper with
        # that fields on the payment form before it goes to PayPal)
        if ipn_obj.receiver_email != "paypalemail@gmail.com":
            # Not a valid payment
            return

        # ALSO: for the same reason, you need to check the amount
        # received, `custom` etc. are all what you expect or what
        # is allowed.

        if ipn_obj.mc_gross == ipn_obj.amount and ipn_obj.mc_currency == 'USD':
            pk = ipn_obj.invoice
            dsr = DatasetRequest.objects.get(pk=pk)
            dsr.is_paid = True
            dsr.save()
    else:
        pass

valid_ipn_received.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

engine/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class EngineConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'engine'

    def ready(self):
        import engine.signals
```

engine/views.py

```
def pay_for_dataset_request(request, dsr_pk):
    # dsr_pk = dataset request primary key

    dsr = DatasetRequest.objects.get(pk=dsr_pk)
    paypal_dict = {
        "business": "paypalemail@gmail.com",
        "amount": dsr.reward,
        "item_name": dsr.title,
        "invoice": dsr.pk,
        "notify_url": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('paypal-ipn')),
        "return": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('datasetrequest_detail', kwargs={'pk': dsr.pk, 'slug': dsr.slug})),
        "cancel_return": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('datasetrequest_detail', kwargs={'pk': dsr.pk, 'slug': dsr.slug})),
    }

    # Create the instance.
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "payment.html", context)
```

"valid_ipn_received" is not firing when i make payments on 127.0.0.1:8000, nor ngrok, nor my production server. What is wrong with my code? I am new to signals.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that your apps.py file is actually being run?  You can test by inserting `breakpoint()` or just a `print()` call.

You may need to add a line to your module's `__init__.py` like so:

```
default_app_config = 'app.engine.apps.EngineConfig'
```

or similar to make sure that it's loaded.  See [the documentation on AppConfigs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#for-application-authors).